# Ancestral state reconstruction of dinosaurs in R

Tags: r, matrix

So I have a data set that looks at the caudal vertebrae of dinosaurs of different groups, which have been split into 5 sections and I have values for those. I'll leave an example of 3.
[image]

Im trying to figure out how I can write a matrix/use this data to create a tree for all my dinosaur species. I have about 150 specimens all split into 5 sections. Paleotree seems to not be loading either for my r not sure whats going on

Comment: You need to provide the code you are using to load your data set and the code you are using to load the Paleotree package. Also any error messages you are receiving.

Answer (score 1):

```
dino <- data.frame(name = c("Apato 1", "Apato 2", "Omeis 1"),
                   split1 = c(-54, 28, -19), 
                   split2 = c(13, -40, 23),
                   split3 = c(-15, -24, 18),
                   split4 = c(-52, -19, -7),
                   split5 = c(-16, -62, -6))

dino[, 2:6] |>
  dist() |>
  hclust() |>
  plot(labels = dino$name)
```

this needs R version 4.1 or above and will yield

[image]

Comment: i tried using paleotree but im not sure how that works. Also what does the dino[, 2;6] define. Finally is there a way i can group these up so that it builds a tree separating the species by the group they belong to. These 3 are of sauropods but I have other types also

Comment: I am not familiar with paleotree but @dcarlson wrote two hours before your comment, that you should post the error messages that came up when you tried to fire up that package. `dino[, 2:6]` tells R that columns 2 to 6 are the ones to compute the distances from, so basically all but the names column. If you need a demonstration of how this works with more dinosaurs, so we can see groups, you should post more example data. Please do not post it as a picture but as code as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example